# Heatmap a hidden non-feature of :vgplot?

Tags: common-lisp

Not being a gnuplot expert (last time I used it was like 25 years ago) and having had some useful applications of Common Lisps `:vgplot` package, this time I wanted to create a heatmap and - to my surprise - I could not find out, how to do it - even after 2 hours of googling and tinkering.

I use sbcl in the usual emacs-slime combo on a debian system.

Loading `vgplot`:

```
(ql:quickload :vgplot)
```

From reading the sources on github and from googling for heatmap examples for "naked" gnuplot, I deduced, that I probably have to use the `(vgplot:surf)` function, which uses `splot` under the hood.
And indeed - I see a 3d mesh plot, when running the function `bla` below:

```
(defun bla ()
       (let* ((xy-range (vgplot:range 0 10))
          (xx (vgplot:meshgrid-x xy-range xy-range))
          (yy (vgplot:meshgrid-y xy-range xy-range))
          (zz (vgplot:meshgrid-map #'+ xx yy)))
         (vgplot:surf xx yy zz)))
```

[image: bla result]

From reading the gnuplot google results, some "pm3d" thing showed up without explanation and I think I need to use `(vgplot:format-plot nil "<something>")` to turn the figure into a heatmap but I could not find out, what exactly I need to do.

Hoping I am not the only one using `vgplot`, I am optimistic, that it is an easy answer for anyone who uses this regularly.

Comment: BTW here's a histogram heatmap example with another graph system (Vegalite) along with 50+ more examples in the Lisp-Stat project: https://lisp-stat.dev/docs/examples/plotting/#histogram-heatmap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use the *palette-mapped three-dimensional* mode `pm3d` of gnuplot. This mode maps three-dimensional data to a color palette, and you can set the `view` to the `map` option to place the viewpoint above the surface.

Here is an example from the [vgplot](http://volkers.github.io/vgplot/vgplot.html) documentation which has been adapted to display as a heatmap:

```lisp
;; Adapted from vgplot documentation for SURF function.
;; Example 3: Plot a function z = f(x,y), e.g. the sombrero function:
(defun example-3-heatmap ()
  (let* ((eps double-float-epsilon)
         (fun #'(lambda (x y)
                  (/ (sin (sqrt (+ (* x x) (* y y) eps)))
                     (sqrt (+ (* x x) (* y y) eps)))))
         (x (vgplot:range -8 8 0.2))
         (y (vgplot:range -8 8 0.2))
         (xx (vgplot:meshgrid-x x y))
         (yy (vgplot:meshgrid-y x y))
         (zz (vgplot:meshgrid-map fun xx yy)))

    ;; Set color palette:
    (vgplot:format-plot
     nil
     "set palette model RGB defined ( -1 'web-green', 0 'goldenrod', 1 'red' )")

    ;; Put gnuplot in pm3d mode:
    (vgplot:format-plot nil "set pm3d")
    (vgplot:format-plot nil "set hidden3d")  ; render opaque surface
    (vgplot:format-plot nil "set view map")  ; view from above

    (vgplot:surf xx yy zz)))
```

Here `format-plot` is used to send a command to `gnuplot` that sets up a palette, then `format-plot` is used to put `gnuplot` into `pm3d` mode, rendering an opaque surface viewed from above.

Philipp Janert has a good book called [Gnuplot in Action](https://www.philipp-janert.com/books/gnuplot-in-action-2nd-edition/) with a section about creating false-color plots (which are heatmaps).

Here is sample output from the above example code:

[image: Example 3 Heatmap]

Comment: the example is from the documentation but do you happen to know why the "eps" term is used here?

Comment: @coredump -- I took that formula directly from the documentation; I assumed that `eps` was used to avoid a floating point error with division by zero. I think that the way `eps` is used the point at the origin gets the Z value for points a distance `(sqrt eps)` from the origin, and all other points undergo a similar radial translation.

Comment: magic! (for non gnuplot experts) :) I was looking for documentation but looks like I was unlucky in my quest...